# How to play videos of any other website into my website using PHP?

Tags: php, video

I want to play a videos of other's website, in to my website. If I use, iframe tag, it will show a full website of third party. i don't want full website, i want to play only the video part. for example, youtube provide the embed video code. it's fine to use youtube videos. but other websites didn't provide, api like youtube, how i use that website's video in to my website. if i use curl library, i can fetch string data of third party website. but i can't fetch video files. how to do that?

Comment: do you have their permission?

Comment: no. i didn't get permission

Comment: then dont steal.

Comment: In pinterest website, i can pin photos from any website. I also want to do the same. but i want to pin videos instead of photos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cant just get any other vídeo from any webpage without permission.

But there is a way such as doing a GET request and then for example in an ajax function displaying only the div that contains the video.

But for this you need permission. Also you can use other APIs such as Vimeo one.

Comment: In pinterest website, i can pin photos from any website.  I also want to do the same. but i want to pin videos instead of photos.